# Is this considered a vertex cover?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reductions, vertex-cover

I'm unsure if this satisfies the definition of vertex cover, the graph is unweighted and undirected:

[image]

if not, an explanation would be super enlighting.

Comment: What definition were you given ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a vertex cover (VC).

By definition, a vertex cover of a graph G=(V,E) is a subset of nodes $U\subset V$ such that $\forall \ e \in E \ \exists u \in U$ such that $e$ is incident in $u$.

Every edge in your graph has one of its extremes in the VC, so yes